# How to wait for free Akka actor while processing stream of data using Plays Iteratee

Tags: asynchronous, playframework, akka, actor, loops

I have infinite stream with messages represented as Plays `Enumerator` to which I apply `Iteratee`. Each message is then processed by Akka actor (number of actors is limited to 10).

Now I would like code in `Iteratee` to asynchronously wait for free actor if all 10 actors are busy and not to send them another messages which leads to exception `Ask timed out on ...`.

**How can I achieve such functionality? Is there a better way to process infinite stream with 10 actors without `await`?**

Example of code I was talking about could look like this:

```
val workers = context.actorOf(Props[MyWorker].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(10)))
val it = Iteratee.foreach[Msg] { msg => 
  workers ? msg
}

msgEnumerator.apply(it)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Iteratee.foldM` with the actor ask pattern you have here is seems like the right approach. Assuming you don't want your actors to build up large mailboxes (if you don't care about large mailboxes, just use `tell` and `Iteratee.foreach` instead of `ask`) This will require some specialized routing logic. Since the api for making a custom akka router doesn't support asynchrony, you will need a custom actor to handle the logic of distributing just one piece of work to each actor in your actor pool at a time.

I imagine it working something like:

```
class WorkDistributor extends Actor {
  final val NUM_WORKERS = 10
  val workers = context.actorOf(Props[MyWorker].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(NUM_WORKERS))) 

  var numActiveWorkers = 0
  var queuedWork: Option[Work] = None

  def receive = {
    case IterateeWork(work) if numActiveWorkers < NUM_WORKERS => workers ! work; numActiveWorkers += 1; sender ! SendMeMoreWork
    case IterateeWork(work) => queuedWork = Some(work)
    case ActorFinishedWork if queuedWork.isDefined => queuedWork.foreach(workers ! _); queuedWork = None
    case ActorFinishedWork => numActiveWorkers -= 1; sender ! SendMeMoreWork
  }
}
```

Where the `IterateeWork` message is sent by the iteratee and the `ActorFinishedWork` message is sent by the actors in the actor pool.

Looking at this thing I wrote, this should be rewritten to use `become` to change the behavior when the actor pool is full (rather than the `if` filters on each case but I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Then your `Iteratee` will look like

```
Iteratee.foldM[Work, SendMeMoreWork.type](SendMeMoreWork) {
  case (_, work) => workDistributor ? IterateeWork(work)
}
```